# Android app build with latest API 30 (Android 10) is only working in Android 10 and when run in Android 8 (OREO) the app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

this is my build gradle file,(Project)
In the grade file You can see sdk versions, minimum sdk version is set to Jelly Beans and the target is set to android 10. The app works fine in Android 10, no issue, but when tried to run in Android version 8 (Oreo) or Android version 7 (Nougat) the app crashes. What to do in that case

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parthan.flairbotstest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    //Converter
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'




}
```

this is the other build gradle(Module APP)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Just let me know if any other files are needed, I tried downgrading the build version to 26.0.2 but in that case too, the app is not running. Thanks!

Here is the crash log

```
2020-10-06 15:48:26.932 9678-9731/com.parthan.flairbotstest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-10-06 15:48:30.328 9678-9678/com.parthan.flairbotstest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.parthan.flairbotstest, PID: 9678
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(253701184bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1739)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Please share the crash log, you should find its stacktrace in your logcat

Comment: I will update the crash log @PerracoLabs

Comment: First: catch the exception so your app will not crash.

Comment: Second: use a smaller image.

Answer (score 2):

The crash stack trace states that the issue is due to an image being too large to be handled.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(253701184bytes) bitmap.
```

Use the the next link provided by Google, for tips about how to load bitmaps more efficiently, and avoid OOM errors:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Besides google official tips, you will find lots of literature around the internet about how to load bitmaps efficiently.